# How to link an anchor tag with a modal in Angular for user logins?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, angularjs

I am trying to recreate a feature where you click on something like a login (shown as JOIN/SIGN-IN in the below pictures from Cozymeal.com, can't post images sorry) and a popdown menu comes, to which you connect using GitHub. I am attempting to do this in Angular, and I had a theory as to how to do this and how this works.

1. Say I am on index.html, I should create an anchor tag (styled to look like a button that says sign-in) that contains a function for ng-click, and upon clicking, it will pull down a modal (using ng-show/hide for the display, and ng-animate for the pulldown effect) that will contain another anchor-tag that links to authentication via GitHub.

Is this a good way to proceed in building this functionality? I set up my routes in Angular, but coming up with this pulldown effect is certainly confusing me.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5AQl.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyTAe.png)

Comment: yes that works. You can also use bootstrap modal for convenience http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it like you just stated, it's also possible to use CSS3 styling in stead of ng-animation and adding the style on click with ng-class and adding a seperate class for closing the menu.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp